# Is it possible to close my account without deleting it ?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I feel like, for some reason, I am not able to ask interesting questions here anymore. So it would probably be better to have my account closed. Still I asked some well-received questions in the past that might be of interest to some people, if any, so I would rather not see them deleted.  Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Just stop using it? What do you want to achieve exactly by "closing" your account?

Comment: I agree with Federico.  Just stop using it.  Your past questions will remain.  If your account is deleted, your past questions will not be identified by "Sylvain JULIEN", but by some numbered name like "user5420741".

Comment: The both of you are right. And not deleting my account will prevent users whose questions I upvoted to lose reputation. It's time for me to dedicate my time to something else. Thanks to all.

Comment: thank _you_ for your contributions to our community, Sylvain --- here's hoping we can welcome you back one day!

Answer (score 4):

Of course. Deletion of your account does not mean your posts are deleted. A complete description of what it means is given here: [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account)

Comment: Ok. Let's do so then.

Comment: Sylvain, you'll have to do this yourself. Instructions are here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account I'm sorry that you feel MathOverflow didn't work out for you.

Comment: It should be noted that any negatively scored post will be deleted. This amounts to 7 answers and some 26 questions, by my count (which is probably wrong).